# C# subscribing to event, when using generic collection of publisher

Tags: c#

What is the best way to subscribe to an event, where the subscriber is using a generic collection of the event publishing class?

To briefly outline, the setup is something like this:

```
public class PublisherClass
{
    public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> DoneSomethingEvent;
...


public class SubscriberClass
{
    public List<PublisherClass> publisherClassList { get; set; }
...
```

Now, if I were to just use `PublisherClass` it would be as simple as:

```
publisherClass.DoneSomethingEvent += MyEventHandler;
```

How do I do this if I'm working with a generic collection of this class?

Comment: A loop, I would imagine.  Be careful though; any user of that class can do something like `publisherClassList[i] = whatever;`, and now you have not subscribed to every event in the list.

Comment: Your safest bet would be to subclass `List<T>` and add events. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) for a starting point.

Comment: You can use a dictionnary instead of a list, a dictionnary also store items like a list but you must put a key value that goes with every item, useful in that case. Retreive the rigth function by is key value

Comment: @ThinkChaos the example you provided in the link only works if the collection itself is changed - it doesn't outline how to attach to an event published by an item within the collection.

Comment: @AaronThomas You are right, I meant you should add events for `Add` and `Remove`, that way you can track changes to the collection and update the events as necessary.

Comment: @ThinkChaos that means an additional set of events. The first set is what I've outlined in my question. The second set would be published by the collection, and fired when the collection changes... surely there is a better way?

Comment: @EdS. looping through would need to be done each time the collection changes. Unfortunately I think your solution is fundamentally the same as ThinkChaos'?

Comment: Yes; that's why a `List<T>` will not suffice.  You would need to use an observable collection type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to put a constraint on the generic type and that constraint would need to be a class or interface that defines the event you are wanting to subscribe to.

```
public interface IDoSomthingPublisher
{
    event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> DoneSomethingEvent;
}

public class PublisherClass : IDoSomthingPublisher
{
    public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> DoneSomethingEvent;
...
}


public class SubscriberClass<T> where T : IDoSomthingPublisher
{
    private List<T> _publisherClassList;

    public List<T> PublisherClassList 
    {
        get
        {
            return _publisherClassList;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_publisherClassList != null)
            {
                foreach(T item in _publisherClassList)
                {
                    //unsubscribe old events
                    item -= MyEventHandler;
                }
            }

            _publisherClassList = value;

            if(_publisherClassList != null)
            {
                foreach(T item in _publisherClassList)
                {
                    //subscribe to new events
                    item += MyEventHandler;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to swap out the `List<T>` to a `ObserveableCollection<T>` so you can get notified if a item is added or removed from the list from outside of your class.

```
public class SubscriberClass<T> where T : IDoSomthingPublisher
{
    private ObserveableCollection<T> _publisherClassList;

    public ObserveableCollection<T> PublisherClassList 
    {
        get
        {
            return _publisherClassList;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_publisherClassList != null)
            {
                _publisherClassList -= CollectionChangedHandler;
                foreach(T item in _publisherClassList)
                {
                    //unsubscribe old events
                    item -= MyEventHandler;
                }
            }

            _publisherClassList = value;

            if(_publisherClassList != null)
            {
                _publisherClassList += CollectionChangedHandler;
                foreach(T item in _publisherClassList)
                {
                    //subscribe to new events
                    item += MyEventHandler;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void CollectionChangedHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
            return; //Don't need to change subscriptions for moves.

        if(args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            throw new NotImplementedException("I leave this to you to solve");

        foreach(var item in args.OldItems)
        {
             item -= MyEventHandler;
        }
        foreach(var item in args.NewItems)
        {
             item += MyEventHandler;
        }
    }
}
```